# Subprocess in Python Add Variables

Tags: python, string

Subprocess in Python Add Variables

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('Schtasks /create /sc  ONCE  /tn  Work  /tr C:\work.exe /st 15:42 /sd 13/10/2010')
```

I want to be able to set the variables on the above command. the variables are the time '15:42' separated in 15 and 42 and the date '13/10/2010' separated in day , month and year any ideas??

Thanx in advance

George

Answer (score 1):

Use [`%` formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) to build the command string.

```
>>> hour,minute = '15','42'
>>> day,month,year = '13','10','2010'
>>> command = 'Schtasks /create /sc  ONCE  /tn  Work  /tr C:\work.exe /st %s:%s /sd %s/%s/%s'
>>> command % (hour,minute, day,month,year)
'Schtasks /create /sc  ONCE  /tn  Work  /tr C:\\work.exe /st 15:42 /sd 13/10/2010'
>>> subprocess.call( command % (hour,minute, day,month,year) )
>>>
```

Comment: The `format` method is preferred since Python 2.6: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess 
time = "15:42"
date = "13/10/2010"
# you can use these variables anyhow take input from user using raw_iput()
subprocess.call('Schtasks /create /sc ONCE /tn Work /tr C:\work.exe /st '+time+' /sd '+date)
```

Comment: how to make string of time and date?

Comment: -1 Formatting strings by summing them isn't the one and only one obvious way to do it.

Comment: @geocheats2 what do u mean by make string of u can use datetime : http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html for using date and time objects and teh required methods for the string format is possible

Answer (score 0):

Python has advanced string formatting capabilities, using the `format` method on strings. For instance:

```
>>> template = "Hello, {name}. How are you today, {date}?"
>>> name = "World"
>>> date = "the fourteenth of October"
>>> template.format(name=name, date=date)
'Hello, World. How are you today, the fourteenth of October?'
```

You can get the time and date using [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) in the `datetime` module:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime("%A %B %Y, %I:%M:%S")
'Wednesday October 2010, 02:54:30'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

subprocess.call(time.strftime("Schtasks /create /sc  ONCE  /tn  Work  /tr C:\work.exe /st %H:%M /sd %d/%m/%Y"))
```

If you would like to change the time you can set it into time object and use it.